# How to avoid overriding files by suffixing a number in ansible?

Tags: ansible, sequence

I do have a command that generates some logs and I want a simple solution for generating sequences of numbers in order to avoid overriding existing files.

- fist execution saves `out.log`
- 2nd execution should create `out2.log`
- 3rd execution should create `out3.log`... and so on.

Currently I do have the variable `output_file=out.log`, so I need a task that would add the suffix, if needed (file already existing on disk).

Ideally this should be implemented using the minimal possible number of ansible tasks.

Comment: Would YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS work?

Comment: You "*want a simple solution*"? Are you sure you wanted to post this on SO not freelancer.com?

Comment: @techraf that's because SO is the best place to obtain optimal solutions to common coding problems, like this one. Don't worry if nobody posts a solution I will answer the question myself. And no, the datestamp is not acceptable but if someone wants to do it in bash I will find it acceptable because I can always use a single task that gets_next_filename. My current implementation is too long and I don't want to embarrass myself with it.

Answer (score 1):

My current solution which I don't like due to its size. If someone else finds a cleaner one I will be more than happy to accept theirs.

This assumes `test_output_file` is the default filename.

```
- name: get next value of test_output_file to avoid overwrites
  shell: |
      path=$(dirname "{{ test_output_file }}")
      filename=$(basename "{{ test_output_file }}")
      extension="${filename##*.}"
      filename="${filename%.*}"
      if [[ -e $path/$filename.$extension ]] ; then
          i=2
          while [[ -e $path/$filename-$i.$extension ]] ; do
              let i++
          done
          filename=$filename-$i
      fi
      echo $path/$filename.$extension
  register: result
  changed_when: False

- name: increments test_output_file if needed
  set_fact:
      test_output_file: "{{ result.stdout_lines[0] }}"
  when: test_output_file != result.stdout_lines[0]
```